# Aligning the ImageView to left the text view to center and checkbox to most right in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am making a activity layout using RelativeLayout i want the image view to be in most left and textview to be in center and checkbox to be in most right but layoutgravity and gravity is not working please can somebody help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Time" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:=""
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Compass" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Map" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in this u use linear layout dear where is relative

Comment: thanks got the solution :) i used relative layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewTime"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Time" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewCompass"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Compass" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewMap"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Map" />

</RelativeLayout>
```